# How to program a counter that iterates in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with 10,000 observations.  I want to program a variable that iterates through the dataset and counts row numbers as 1, 2, 3, then resets again at 1.  So, if the variable was "count" then row 1, count=1, row 2, count=2, row 3, count=3, but row 4, count=1, row 5 count=2, etc.  This program is in SAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `data` step, you can create a counter variable using `_N_` and the [modulo](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/59656/HTML/default/viewer.htm#langref_sect173.htm) command:

```
counter = mod(_N_-1,3) + 1
```

Should give you:

```
Index    Counter
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        1
5        2
6        3
.        .
.        .
.        .
```

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty easy.

```
data want;
    set have;
    count=mod(_N_-1,3)+1;
run;
```